# Create a dynamic action on an interactive report to display data when a selected number a chosen

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5y5rJ.png)

When the user clicks on the drop down and selects the number ,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZ0Iv.png)

The data that should be displayed should contain only data where the branch is equal to '004'

I tried using javascript to perform this action but it did not work

Answer (score 1):

Here is a similar example on the emp/dept sample schema. This can be installed via SQL Workshop > Utilities > Sample Datasets > "EMP / DEPT". The functionality is that the user has a select list on departments. When user selects value, the report shows all the employees in that department in an IR. Same as you are asking, just on different data. If you have trouble converting this to your code I'd suggest replicating this, and then converting to your tables step by step:

- Create page item P165_DEPT of type "Select List" with source type "SQL Query" and source

```
SELECT dname, deptno FROM dept
```

- Create a region of type interactive report on table `EMP` with following where clause and items to submit:

[image]

- Create a dynamic action on "Change" of "P165_DEPT" with a true action of type "Refresh", select type "Region", region: your region:

[image]

Run the page, select a department and see the magic happen :)

[image]

Comment: I am simulating the example you put up to the answer to my question and im still trying to find where the deptno is could you elaborate on that column? cause i dont see it on data contained in the interactive report that you shared

Comment: Good catch. The column "Department" is of type Plain Text (based on List of Values) and references a list of values that maps the dname to deptno. So in my example it shows the department name, but if you have a column type of "Plain Text" it will show the actual deptno value.

Comment: the select query you used source listed the deptno as a column so this explanation you gave me its hard for me to make the correlation , and at the end of your last reply you stated "but if you have a column type of "Plain Text" it will show the actual deptno value" make me understand where that column is from again

Comment: This whole comment trail has nothing to do with the original question: a dynamic action to refresh a report. I answered that question but this accidentally creeped into my solution. I'm more than happy to explain to you how the column type "Plain Text (based on List of Values)" works but that is very hard in the comments. I suggest you file a new question for that.

Answer (score 1):

Koen's suggestion is one way to do it, but - I'd say that you can do it **even simpler** (yes, I know - you specified that you want to create a dynamic action). The following text is related to his example.

- create interactive report whose `where` clause contains

  ```
  where deptno = :P165_DEPT
  ```

  (no need to set any other settings at the moment)
- create `P165_DEPT` Select List item and set its **Page action on selection** to **Submit page**:

  [image]

That's all; once you select a new department, Page action will submit the page (along with `P165_DEPT` item) and refresh the interactive report, showing only rows that satisfy the `where` condition.

That shouldn't spoil anything (i.e. unnecessarily submit some other items as it seems that there aren't any on your page).